# Blog: Simple Storage Patterns in Solidity

Tags: discussion, blog, blog-overflow

*Posted in relation to the [blog initiative](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/414/introducing-ethereum-blog-overflow).*

---

Simple and appropriate data organization can challenge Solidity newcomers. It  wants us to organize everything in ways many of us aren’t accustomed to. 
Here are *some* simple and useful patterns in increasing order of capability.

**Simple List using Array**

Strengths

- In the order of declaration (chronological)
- Provides a count (rows)
- Random access by Row Number (not ID)

Weaknesses

- No random access by Id
- No assurance of uniqueness.
- No check for duplicates.
- Uncontrolled growth of the list

> ```
>     contract simpleList {
>
>         struct EntityStruct {
>             address entityAddress;
>             uint entityData;
>             // more fields
>         }
>
>         EntityStruct[] public entityStructs;
>
>         function newEntity(address entityAddress, uint entityData) public returns(uint rowNumber) {
>             EntityStruct memory newEntity;
>             newEntity.entityAddress = entityAddress;
>             newEntity.entityData    = entityData;
>             return entityStructs.push(newEntity)-1;
>         }
>
>         function getEntityCount() public constant returns(uint entityCount) {
>             return entityStructs.length;
>         }
>     }
> ```

**Mapping with Struct**

Strengths

- Random Access by unique Id
- Assurance of Id uniqueness
- Enclose complex arrays, mappings, structs within each “record”

Weaknesses

- Unable to enumerate the keys
- Unable to count the keys
- Needs a manual check to distinguish a default from an explicit record

> contract mappingWithStruct {
>
> ```
>     struct EntityStruct {
>         uint entityData;
>         bool isEntity;
>     }
>
>     mapping (address => EntityStruct) public entityStructs;
>
>     function isEntity(address entityAddress) public constant returns(bool isIndeed) {
>         return entityStructs[entityAddress].isEntity;
>     }
>
>     function newEntity(address entityAddress, uint entityData) public returns(bool success) {
>         if(isEntity(entityAddress)) throw; 
>         entityStructs[entityAddress].entityData = entityData;
>         entityStructs[entityAddress].isEntity = true;
>         return true;
>     }
>
>     function deleteEntity(address entityAddress) public returns(bool success) {
>         if(!isEntity(entityAddress)) throw;
>         entityStructs[entityAddress].isEntity = false;
>         return true;
>     }
>
>     function updateEntity(address entityAddress, uint entityData) public returns(bool success) {
>         if(!isEntity(entityAddress)) throw;
>         entityStructs[entityAddress].entityData = entityData;
>         return true;
>     }
> }
> ```

**Array of Structs with Unique Ids**

Strengths

- Random Access by row number
- Assurance of Id uniqueness
- Enclose complex arrays, mappings and structs within each “record”

Weaknesses

- No random access by Id
- Uncontrolled growth of the list

> ```
> contract arrayWithUniqueIds {
>
>     struct EntityStruct {
>         address entityAddress;
>         uint entityData;
>     }
>
>     EntityStruct[] public entityStructs;
>     mapping(address => bool) knownEntity;
>
>     function isEntity(address entityAddress) public constant returns(bool isIndeed) {
>         return knownEntity[entityAddress];
>     }
>
>     function getEntityCount() public constant returns(uint entityCount) {
>         return entityStructs.length;
>     }
>
>     function newEntity(address entityAddress, uint entityData) public returns(uint rowNumber) {
>         if(isEntity(entityAddress)) throw;
>         EntityStruct newEntity;
>         newEntity.entityAddress = entityAddress;
>         newEntity.entityData = entityData;
>         knownEntity[entityAddress] = true;
>         return entityStructs.push(newEntity) - 1;
>     }
>
>     function updateEntity(uint rowNumber, address entityAddress, uint entityData) public returns(bool success) {
>         if(!isEntity(entityAddress)) throw;
>         if(entityStructs[rowNumber].entityAddress != entityAddress) throw;
>         entityStructs[rowNumber].entityData    = entityData;
>         return true;
>     }
> }
> ```

**Mapped Structs with Delete-enabled Index**

Strengths

- Random Access by unique Id or row number
- Assurance of Id Uniqueness
- Enclose complex arrays, mappings and structs within each “record”
- Count the records/Ids
- Enumerate the Ids
- Ability to logically control the size of the active list

Weaknesses

- Marginally increased code complexity
- Higher storage cost than alternatives
- Key list is inherently unordered

Detailed description: https://medium.com/@robhitchens/solidity-crud-part-1-824ffa69509a#.20k69nqrc

```
contract mappedWithUnorderedIndexAndDelete {

    struct EntityStruct {
        uint entityData;
        uint listPointer;
    }

    mapping(address => EntityStruct) public entityStructs;
    address[] public entityList;

    function isEntity(address entityAddress) public constant returns(bool isIndeed) {
        if(entityList.length == 0) return false;
        return (entityList[entityStructs[entityAddress].listPointer] == entityAddress);
    }

    function getEntityCount() public constant returns(uint entityCount) {
        return entityList.length;
    }

    function newEntity(address entityAddress, uint entityData) public returns(bool success) {
        if(isEntity(entityAddress)) throw;
        entityStructs[entityAddress].entityData = entityData;
        entityStructs[entityAddress].listPointer = entityList.push(entityAddress) - 1;
        return true;
    }

    function updateEntity(address entityAddress, uint entityData) public returns(bool success) {
        if(!isEntity(entityAddress)) throw;
        entityStructs[entityAddress].entityData = entityData;
        return true;
    }

    function deleteEntity(address entityAddress) public returns(bool success) {
        if(!isEntity(entityAddress)) throw;
        uint rowToDelete = entityStructs[entityAddress].listPointer;
        address keyToMove   = entityList[entityList.length-1];
        entityList[rowToDelete] = keyToMove;
        entityStructs[keyToMove].listPointer = rowToDelete;
        entityList.length--;
        return true;
    }

}
```

There are certainly more ways of combining structs, arrays and mappings. Do you have favorite or interesting pattern? Show us how it works!

Comment: Kudos if anyone can get the formatting to cooperate.

Comment: Closed as per Stack Exchange Staff suggestion.